# Does an Interrupted UPDATE still manipulate data?

Tags: sql-server

i have fired an 'update' query by mistake. But while processing i canceled the transaction. I want to know during that time of execution and cancellation has any data got manipulated.

Comment: Have you tried checking a few of the rows to see if the values have changed?

Comment: Did you mean SQL Server or MySql?

Answer (score 1):

What sort of query?

If it was a plain SELECT, then no damage will have been done.

If it was in a transaction, then the transaction should have been rolled back - and any damage should have been undone.

If the operation was not running in a transaction, the behaviour will be DBMS-specific.  Most will treat statements as atomic - either it completes or it is as if the statement was never executed.  Not all do things that way, though.

It would help if you specified which DBMS you are using - there can be differences in the answer depending on the nuances of the DBMS in question.

Comment: I would guess he is using MySql since he tagged it as such.

Comment: @MitMaro - it was tagged 'mysql'; now it is tagged 'ms-sql'.  That's a bit indecisive.

Answer (score 0):

> But while processing i **cancelled the
>   transaction.**

[WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) -
Basically, if it was a transaction, and you canceled it before it finished, then whatever had started would have been undone.  What your database looks like now should be the same as it looked before the UPDATE.

Comment: NO, i cant tell b'coz the data is in a huge pile. so i cant say anyting. But just want to know bout the same.